# Pig: ERROR 1045: Could not infer the matching function for COUNT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to count the tweets per user through Pig. But I seem to bump into an issue. Me and a classmate are using Apache Pig (actually Hadoop and all the different components as a whole) for the first time. We are trying to follow a little case about Twitter which provided us with some code. But when we try to perform the COUNT it gives us the following error:

> ERROR 1045: Could not infer the matching function for COUNT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

We tried to do some research on the internet, but it is just hard to find a solution. We tried running it with "Pig -x local" but also through HDFS.

What we're trying to do is to perform a COGROUP on two tables, followed by a COUNT to count the amount of tweets per user.

For extra info: We are running this on AWS by Amazon. I don't know if that might be helpful.

Link to the tutorial, just in case: https://www.edureka.co/blog/pig-tutorial/
Link to a pastebin of the DUMP of the COGROUP between the two tables: https://pastebin.com/DAFhAJV4

This is the code we have so far:

```
UserData = LOAD 'hdfs://ourip/data/userv5.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (Id:int,UserName:chararray);
TweetData = LOAD 'hdfs://ourip/data/tweetsv5.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (UserId:int,Text:chararray);

groupby_user2 = COGROUP TweetData by 'UserId', UserData by 'Id';

count = FOREACH groupby_user2 GENERATE COUNT(Id);
dump COUNT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues with the code you've shared above.

1. You're using the name `count` for one of your relations which could lead to ambiguity as to whether you mean the alias `count` or the function `count`. I would recommend using a different name like `twitter_count` for example.
2. Relation names are case sensitive so if you define a relation called `twitter_count` and then try `dump TWITTER_COUNT` you will get an error.

I think the error you quoted in your question is some combination of 1 and 2 above.

3. Even if you fix the problems I've mentioned, you will still see an error when you do `COUNT(Id)`:

   ```
   Invalid field projection. Projected field [Id] does not exist in schema:
   group:chararray,TweetData:bag{:tuple(UserID:chararray)},UserData:bag{:tuple(Id:chararray)}
   ```

   This is because Id is nested within the bag `UserData` so you would need to specify `COUNT(UserData.Id)`. But is this what you mean to count? This would give you the number of users for each group (probably 1). I think you mean to count the number of tweets which would be something like:

   ```
   twitter_count = FOREACH groupby_user2 GENERATE COUNT(TweetData);
   dump twitter_count;
   ```